# Update value in JSON as a string in database

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my sql table there is field called `activity` which contains value like `[{"sports":50}]`. Now I want to rename `sports` to `activites`. How do i can do this using a sql `update` statement. Need to keep value `50` as it is.

From `[{"sports":50}]` to `[{"activites":50}]`

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't store JSON strings or comma separated values in mysql. Instead, you should have a 2nd table with a key that relates back to the main table that has this data in it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this in MSSQL, but I'm sure this would work for you too.

```
UPDATE t SET t.ACTIVITY = REPLACE(t2.ACTIVITY, 'sports', 'activity')
FROM dbo.test1 t
INNER JOIN dbo.test1 t2 ON t2.ID = t.ID
```

Comment: The self-join makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The array doesn't make sense for what you are saving and makes this a lot harder than it has to be.

A safe way to do this, is to unnest the array elements, replace the key and then aggregate them back.

```
update the_table
  set activity = (select jsonb_agg(
                          case 
                            when item ? 'sports' then jsonb_build_object('acitivity', item -> 'sports')
                            else item 
                          end)
                   from jsonb_array_elements(activity) as e(item))
```

If you are 100% certain you don't have keys that *contain* the string `sports` (e.g. `'sportscar'`, you can do a brute force replacement:

```
update the_table
   set activitiy = replace(activity::text, 'sports', 'activity)::jsonb
```

---

This would be a lot easier with a properly normalized data model